# Static date formula not working in Excel Table

Tags: excel, date, static

I have a table with column names as "Approved Date" and "Status" and I want the Approved Date to be filled with the date when I fill the corresponding Status column with "Completed"

I tried using this formula and its not working.

```
=IF([@Status]<>"Complete",0,IF([@[Approved Date]]=0,TODAY(),0))
```

And I do not want the date to be changed every day but need to remain constant. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I also checked the "Enable iterative calculation" in Options. I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: You are using `TODAY()` in your formula, which will update every day regardless.  The only way to prevent that is to convert the formula to a value (copy -> paste special -> value) so that it doesn't have a formula to update anymore.  If you need the conversion to value automated, this will require VBA.

Comment: I understand that however the second if loop should prevent that from happening right. This will update the date only when the value in Status column is changed.

Comment: No, once the formula evaluates to the `TODAY()` portion, the rest won't matter.  It will update every day.

Comment: I am sure that this works because I am using this in other sheets. But I am trouble to make this work with Table.